# Schrodingers JSON - when working with a json doc it is erroring as both a list and a dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a Python list from an API call:

```
[{'_id': '5f563c1bf8eaa9d98eca231f',
  'allEnabledDs': None,
  'allEnabledIdSor': None,
  'correlationFilterEntitySource': True,
  'correlation_completed': True,
  'correlation_completed_dt': '2020-09-07T13:56:43.547Z',
  'created_at': '2020-09-07T13:56:43.469Z',
  'dsConnectionList': None,
  'folderToLabelMapping': None,
  'idConnectionList': None,
  'identities_scanned': 0,
  'identityResolutionScan': False,
  'info': None,
  'isCustomScanProfile': None,
  'modelId': None,
  'name': 'Identity Discovery Scan',
  'origin': 'Identity Discovery Scan',
  'piisummary_completed_dt': '2020-09-07T13:56:43.642Z',
  'scan_progress_status': {'Started': '2020-09-07T13:56:43.469Z'},
  'shouldCreateClassifiers': None,
  'skipIdScan': None,
  'state': 'Started',
  'stopRequested': True,
  'type': 'identityDiscoveryScan',
  'updated_at': '2020-09-07T16:59:45.294Z'}]
```

And this is my code:

```
    for i in live_scans:
        url = url 
        payload = {}
        headers = {
            "Authorization": token
        }
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
        j_doc = r.json()
        d = {k:v for k,v in (x.split(':') for x in j_doc)}
        if j_doc['state'] == "Stopped":
            print("YAY!")
        if d['state'] == "Stopped":
            print("YAY!")
```

However when using this code:

```
if n_dict['state'] == "Stopped":
        print("YAY!")
```

This error occurs:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str>
```

And when attempting to split the list into a dict with:

```
d = {k:v for k,v in (x.split(':') for x in j_doc)}
```

Can someone give me a pointer into why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: The code you've posted at the top of your question (which is not JSON) looks like a list of dicts. I don't know what you intended your "full code" to do with that. You seem to trying to call `split` on a dict. It doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Nowhere does a reference to `n_dict` appear in the the supposedly full code you posted.

Comment: Isn't it a list of dict? So you can try `n_dict[0]['state'] == 'Stopped'` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Hitobat mentioned in commend - you have list with dictionary inside so you have to use `[0]` to get this dictionary. Or you have to use `for`-loop if you have more elements on list

```
data = [{'_id': '5f563c1bf8eaa9d98eca231f', 'allEnabledDs': None, 'allEnabledIdSor': None, 'correlationFilterEntitySource': True, 'created_at': '2020-09-07T13:56:43.469Z', 'dsConnectionList': None, 'folderToLabelMapping': None, 'idConnectionList': None, 'identityResolutionScan': False, 'info': None, 'isCustomScanProfile': None, 'modelId': None, 'name': 'Identity Discovery Scan', 'origin': 'Identity Discovery Scan', 'scan_progress_status': {'Started': '2020-09-07T13:56:43.469Z'}, 'shouldCreateClassifiers': None, 'skipIdScan': None, 'state': 'Started', 'type': 'identityDiscoveryScan', 'updated_at': '2020-09-07T16:59:45.294Z', 'identities_scanned': 0, 'correlation_completed': True, 'correlation_completed_dt': '2020-09-07T13:56:43.547Z', 'piisummary_completed_dt': '2020-09-07T13:56:43.642Z', 'stopRequested': True}]

print( data[0]['state'] )

for item in data:
    print( item['state'] )
```

---

Next time you can use `type()` to check what you have -

```
print( type(data) )
```

if it `list` then you can test length and/or check first element

```
print( len(data) )
print( type( data[0] ) )
```

if it is `dict` then you can check what keys you can use

```
print( data[0].keys() )
```

This way you can recognize how to get expected element(s).

You can also use `json` to format it with indentations and see how it looks like

```
import json

print( json.dumps(data, indent=2) )
```

Results:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5f563c1bf8eaa9d98eca231f",
    "allEnabledDs": null,
    "allEnabledIdSor": null,
    "correlationFilterEntitySource": true,
    "created_at": "2020-09-07T13:56:43.469Z",
    "dsConnectionList": null,
    "folderToLabelMapping": null,
    "idConnectionList": null,
    "identityResolutionScan": false,
    "info": null,
    "isCustomScanProfile": null,
    "modelId": null,
    "name": "Identity Discovery Scan",
    "origin": "Identity Discovery Scan",
    "scan_progress_status": {
      "Started": "2020-09-07T13:56:43.469Z"
    },
    "shouldCreateClassifiers": null,
    "skipIdScan": null,
    "state": "Started",
    "type": "identityDiscoveryScan",
    "updated_at": "2020-09-07T16:59:45.294Z",
    "identities_scanned": 0,
    "correlation_completed": true,
    "correlation_completed_dt": "2020-09-07T13:56:43.547Z",
    "piisummary_completed_dt": "2020-09-07T13:56:43.642Z",
    "stopRequested": true
  }
]
```

Similar way you can use `pprint` (Pretty Print)

```
import pprint

pprint.pprint(data)
```

Result:

```
[{'_id': '5f563c1bf8eaa9d98eca231f',
  'allEnabledDs': None,
  'allEnabledIdSor': None,
  'correlationFilterEntitySource': True,
  'correlation_completed': True,
  'correlation_completed_dt': '2020-09-07T13:56:43.547Z',
  'created_at': '2020-09-07T13:56:43.469Z',
  'dsConnectionList': None,
  'folderToLabelMapping': None,
  'idConnectionList': None,
  'identities_scanned': 0,
  'identityResolutionScan': False,
  'info': None,
  'isCustomScanProfile': None,
  'modelId': None,
  'name': 'Identity Discovery Scan',
  'origin': 'Identity Discovery Scan',
  'piisummary_completed_dt': '2020-09-07T13:56:43.642Z',
  'scan_progress_status': {'Started': '2020-09-07T13:56:43.469Z'},
  'shouldCreateClassifiers': None,
  'skipIdScan': None,
  'state': 'Started',
  'stopRequested': True,
  'type': 'identityDiscoveryScan',
  'updated_at': '2020-09-07T16:59:45.294Z'}]
```